# Inserting into database via JavaScript AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Let's say I have a form that has multiple inputs. Like an array... so we'd have:

```
<input name='firstname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='lastname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='dob[]' type='text' value='' /> 
<input name='firstname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='lastname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='dob[]' type='text' value='' /> 
<input name='firstname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='lastname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='dob[]' type='text' value='' /> 
<input name='firstname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='lastname[]' type='text' value='' /> <input name='dob[]' type='text' value='' />
```

Imagine instead of 4, there is like 50. OK, so the way I do it right now is through a regular HTML form submission using PHP like so:

```
foreach ($_POST['firstname'] as $fname) {
...
}
```

Anyway, would it be better to do it through a JavaScript `foreach` event where each submission is submitted or do one simple AJAX request then after that one is finished.. go to the next one until the submissions is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP requests are (in relative terms) very time consuming.

Send all the data in one go, just as you do with a regular form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the Form elements and send as JSON to the other side.

`var data = $("form").serialize()`

`$.ajax({`
`...`
`data:data`
`.....`

`})`